# Como por Variável Javascript dentro de um value do html?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
console.log(ArmazenaIds);
console.log(ArmazenaEmails);
contaQuantidadeDeEmails = ArmazenaEmails.length;
//listando emails selecionados na div .top 
for( c=0; c<contaQuantidadeDeEmails; c++) {

  $('ul').append('<li>'+ArmazenaEmails[c]+'</li>');
  // COLOCANDO CADA EMAIL DENTRO DO VALUE PRA ENVIAR PELO FORM
  //USANDO AJAX
  $('#novo').append("<input type='hidden' name='emailzinhos[]' value='aff' /> ");
}
```

Como faço para colocar o vetor `ArmazenaEmails[c]` dentro do `value='aff'`, não sei como fazer isso, tentei com + e tá me dando erro de sintaxe, é uma pergunta até fácil só não sei a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a seleção da *tag* `input` com o valor `"aff"`.

Basta adicionar a seguinte instrução:

```
$('input[value="aff"]').val(ArmazenaEmails[c]);
```

Ficando assim:

```
console.log(ArmazenaIds);
console.log(ArmazenaEmails);
contaQuantidadeDeEmails = ArmazenaEmails.length;
//listando emails selecionados na div .top 
for( c=0; c<contaQuantidadeDeEmails; c++) {

  $('ul').append('<li>'+ArmazenaEmails[c]+'</li>');
  // COLOCANDO CADA EMAIL DENTRO DO VALUE PRA ENVIAR PELO FORM
  //USANDO AJAX
  $('#novo').append("<input type='hidden' name='emailzinhos[]' value='aff' /> ");
  $('input[value="aff"]').val(ArmazenaEmails[c]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode concatenar os valores do vetor `ArmazenaEmails[c]` na string:

```
for( c=0; c<contaQuantidadeDeEmails; c++) {
  $('ul').append('<li>'+ArmazenaEmails[c]+'</li>');
  // COLOCANDO CADA EMAIL DENTRO DO VALUE PRA ENVIAR PELO FORM
  //USANDO AJAX
  $('#novo').append("<input type='hidden' name='emailzinhos[]' value='"+ArmazenaEmails[c]+"' /> ");
}
```

Neste exemplo, vou retirar o `hidden` dos `inputs` para poder visualizar o valor:

```js
ArmazenaEmails = ['abc@email.com','def@email.com','ghi@email.com'];

contaQuantidadeDeEmails = ArmazenaEmails.length;
//listando emails selecionados na div .top 
for( c=0; c<contaQuantidadeDeEmails; c++) {
  $('ul').append('<li>'+ArmazenaEmails[c]+'</li>');
  // COLOCANDO CADA EMAIL DENTRO DO VALUE PRA ENVIAR PELO FORM
  //USANDO AJAX
  $('#novo').append("<input type='' name='emailzinhos[]' value='"+ArmazenaEmails[c]+"' /> ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="novo">
   <ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: NOSSA ERA ISSO QUE EU TAVA QUERENDOOOOOOO DVD, NÃO SABIA QUE DAVA PRA CONCATENAR ASSIM QUE LEGALLLL